# Lifecycle management

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs

I'm using chrome custom tabs through [this](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) SDK. I'm integrating an openid connect solution which on some custom scope requires the user to receive an SMS one time password, and then input it in the next screen.
All works great EXCEPt if the user actually switches app to read the SMS ( if read from notification all is ok), when the user tries to return to the tab/app it closes/disappears etc..

is there a way to "force" or store the session/browser state?

Comment: From your description, it seems that the Custom Tab activity closes when you switch to the SMS app and back. Can you confirm the SMS is opened in a different App the the one that has the Custom Tab. It doesn't look like it's the expected behaviour. Can you see any errors on logcat?

Comment: actually the problem , we just found out, was this flag: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in our case the problem was being set with a flag:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Make sure the flag is correctly set to maintain history and the activity with the custom tab will not close upon losing focus